# Tool to determine how long an HTTP request takes till finish

Tags: http, httprequest

I need a tool to determine how long it takes the page to be fully loaded (from the start of my HTTP request), preferably something that can be run client-side and (not critical) permits logging for statistics.

Is there such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox with the Firebug add-on. Does the initial page load along with separating each type of item and individual items (like images, js, etc). It also measures XHR requests individually.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ as well as one of its add-ons: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/addons/neXpert.asp do this and much more. Here is a demo of the Fiddler add on which even makes recommendations for performance tuning based on this information: https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?EventID=1032398774&EventCategory=5&culture=en-US&CountryCode=US.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 developer tools > Network tab